# How would I activate my script on button click only?

Tags: javascript

So my HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<head>
    <script src="js/problem1.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Problem #1" onclick="problem1();" />
    <script src="js/problem1.js"></script>
</body>
```

The script I am trying to run is:

```
var counter = 0   
var total = 0    
var start = prompt("Enter a number here to find the sum of all numbers that are:\n-Between 0 and your number\n-Divisible by 3 or 5")

    function problem1(start) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < start; counter++) {   
            if (counter < start) { 
                if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                    total += counter;
                }
                else if (counter % 5 == 0) {
                    total += counter;
                }
            }
            else if (counter == start) {
                if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                    total += counter;
                    alert(total);
                }
                else if (counter % 5 == 0) {
                    total += counter;
                    alert(total);
                }
                else {
                    alert(total);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I am running into is that right now the script runs on page load and instantly gives me a prompt for creating the `start` variable. After entering an integer and clicking `Ok` the prompt window disappears and nothing happens.  I do realize that the script is running on its own because it is called in the `<head>`. Problem is I don't know how else to call it, like on button click. I don't want to use JQuery. I have seen lots of answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180712/how-to-run-script-when-a-button-is-clicked) but I am looking for something that doesn't require JQuery. How would I accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the help. Now I have stumbled upon a second problem. I can't get the script to run or display the alert (not sure which)

Comment: Your `prompt()` is outside your function which get's called by the button click. Simply move the `var start = prompt(...)` into your function. Also move your `var counter = 0` and `var total = 0` into the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your prompt inside the problem function

```js
function problem1() {
    var counter = 0   
    var total = 0    
    var start = prompt("Enter a number here to find the sum of all numbers that are:\n-Between 0 and your number\n-Divisible by 3 or 5")

    for (counter = 0; counter < start; counter++) {   
        if (counter < start) { 
            if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                total += counter;
                alert(total);
            }
            else if (counter % 5 == 0) {
                total += counter;
                alert(total);
            }

        }
        else if (counter == start) {
            if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                total += counter;
                alert(total);
            }
            else if (counter % 5 == 0) {
                total += counter;
                alert(total);
            }
            else {
                alert(total);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE> 
<head>
    <script src="js/problem1.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Problem #1" onclick="problem1();" />
    <script src="js/problem1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This did it thank you. But now I found that the alert box isn't showing....

Comment: @Weber because you did not put alert in your first condition

Comment: @NewbeeDev not actually, because the loop condition is set as counter < start, which will never reach counter == start, that's why the else if part wont trigger hence no alert

Comment: @Weber, change:
`for (counter = 0; counter < start ; counter++) `
to:
`for (counter = 0; counter <= start; counter++)`

Comment: @Weber the instruction was ("Enter a number here to find the sum of all numbers that are:\n-Between 0 and your number\n-Divisible by 3 or 5") so it was a range from 0 to his inputted number so the loop condition is correct. I guess you thought it was the start counter because of it's variable naming can't blame you too.

Comment: @NewbeeDev, say the input number is 10, number divisible by 3 or 5 will be: `3,5,6,9,10` which should alert 33. But the loop condition is set to check if counter < input number, which means the loop will run until  9 < 10, and stop running when 10<10. The else if part is to alert the total when counter == input number which requires 10 == 10. Hope this clarifies

Comment: @Sean W. that was the problem. Thank you both for all of your help.